# Why can't my PHP code see $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

Tags: php

I am currently restructuring some code - and file extensions - and I'm having trouble understanding why this code no longer works, just because I changed the file extension. I am relatively new to PHP but have a fair bit of experience with HTML and CSS; there is clearly something I don't understand about file extensions and/or including PHP files within HTML.

Here's my situation. I have a file called contact.php which is HTML with just a few PHP include statements to embed various fragments into my web pages. One of my includes is this:

This is the footer fragment, which gets included on every page of the website:

```
<br>
<div id="footer">
<div class="row">
<div class="col" id="updated">
<?php include '%WestownFunctions.php'; ?>
<?php getLastUpdate(); ?>
</div id="updated">
<div class="col" id="copyright">
<?php getCopyright(); ?>
</div id="copyright">
</div class="row">
</div id="footer">
```

This, in turn, is %Westown.Functions.php:

```
<?php

function getLastUpdate() {

    $filename = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    echo "getLastUpdate() filename: " . $filename . " "; //temporary!
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
    echo "This page, " . substr($filename,1) . ", was last updated on: " . date('M j Y \a\t H:i:s T.', getlastmod());
}

function getCopyright() {

    $filename = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    echo "getCopyright() filename: " . $filename . " "; //temporary!
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
    echo "(c) " . date('Y', getlastmod()) . " - Westown";   
}

?>
```

This all works very well just the way it is: the page displays properly, including everything desired of the footer.

The changes I've made have been to replace the PHP includes in contact.php with server-side includes so that they all look like this:

```
<!--#include file='fragments/_footer.shtml' -->
```

I have *ALSO* renamed contact.php to contact.html.

The server-side includes work perfectly but there's one hitch: the two functions in %WestownFunctions.php apparently can't see $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] because the $filename variable is blank when I echo it in both functions. I don't understand why I'm getting that behaviour: %WestownFunctions.php *is* a PHP file and all that I've changed is the file extension on the contact.php file and the type of include I am doing.

Can someone kindly explain why I'm having this problem?

I know the old rule that says "if something works, don't fix it" but I'm trying to make the code follow professional standards as closely as I can. I am under the impression that it is "better" for an HTML file that contains no PHP to have an .html extension. I managed to get all of the PHP out of the original contact.php by using SSIs instead of PHP includes so now it seems logical to change the file extension to .html [was ".php" in the original version of the question but that's not what I meant]. But doing so obviously breaks the PHP that gets invoked on the included page. Should I rename contact.html back to contact.php? Should I restore the PHP includes instead of using the SSIs?

Comment: `.html` will not execute `php` code.

Comment: _"I am under the impression that it is 'better' for an HTML file that contains no PHP to have an .html extension."_ - better _how_, in regards to what measure exactly? // "Professional standards" these days would IMHO rather be to eliminate "file suffixes" from main document URLs completely. When it comes to user friendliness and clean looking URLs, then `example.com/contact` beats both `example.com/contact.php` or `example.com/contact.html` by lengths.

Comment: @04FS Unfortunately, removing the file extension entirely means my IDE, Eclipse, does not know what editor to use and I lose all my colour-coding of statements. How do I deal with that? I did it anyway, just to see what would happen and now neither the SSIs nor the PHP includes work. It seems to me that file extensions remain essential for things to work.

Comment: _"How do I deal with that?"_ - by realizing the difference between URLs / the HTTP context, and the file system. URLs _can_ match onto the file system 1:1, but they don't have to. _URL rewriting_ is the keyword here, if you want to circle back to "professional standards" as of today.

Comment: @04FS I was unaware of URL rewriting until you mentioned it just now. Having done a bit of research since your last comment, I now understand that you're NOT proposing changing any file names in my IDE or what is uploaded to the server. You only mean to change the name that *users* see via MOD_REWRITE rules. Thank you for acquainting me with this idea and clarifying what you meant in your original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSI will simply pull in a file and assume it's a chunk of HTML; any PHP tags inside that file (even if named with a `.php` extension) will be served verbatim to the browser, *not* interpreted by the server as PHP.

tl;dr: You need to put back your PHP `include`.

Comment: The corollary to that seems to be that I also have to rename contact.html to contact.php; using a PHP include while the file name remained contact.html did NOT work: the PHP include got commented out by whatever component interpreted it on the server.

Comment: Second corollary: all the SSIs need to be changed back to PHP includes otherwise THEY won't work either, even if they are only bringing in a pure HTML file. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is also possible to configure your web server to treat ``.html`` files as PHP, i.e. to interpret any PHP inside them. However, I would not recommend doing this.